# location = / не работает

Tags: nginx

Хочу прописать особые параметры для главной страницы.

В документации [написано](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location):

> location = / { *[ конфигурация А ]* }
>
> Для запроса “/” будет выбрана конфигурация А

Вот я и пишу у себя:

```
$ cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test.conf
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name example.ru;

  location = / {
    root /var/www/test;
    expires 0;
  }
}

$ sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Все файлы есть и права доступа правильные:

```
$ ls -alh /var/www/test
итого 12K
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4,0K авг 24 18:45 .
drwxr-xr-x  9 root www-data 4,0K авг 24 18:45 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root       19 авг 24 18:45 index.html

$ cat /var/www/test/index.html
<h1>It works!</h1>
```

Но в браузере я вижу стандартную страницу nginx.

Кэш естественно почищен, и даже режим инкогнито попробован.

Почему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хех, кинул ссылку на [документацию про index](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html) и там же нашёл причину проблемы:

> Необходимо иметь в виду, что при использовании индексного файла делается **внутреннее перенаправление** и запрос может быть обработан уже в другом location’е.

И так как по умолчанию прописывается `index index.html;`, то запрос, пришедший в `location = /`, уходит в `/index.html`, для которого я настройки не написал.

Так что нужно их написать:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name example.ru;

  # На самом деле этот location вообще не нужен,
  # если используются настройки по умолчанию
  location = / {
    root /var/www/test;
    # index index.html; прописывается по умолчанию
  }

  # А вот этот location как раз очень нужен
  location = /index.html {
    root /var/www/test;
    expires 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Кажется я понял в чём проблема. У вас в блоке `location` не указана директива `index`. Эта директива указывает файл, который должен отправляться при запросах, оканчивающихся на `/`. На вашем скрине я вижу, что путь именно `/`.

Nginx работает по такой логике: запрос оканчивается на `/`?

Да - показать файл указанный в директиве `index`, если это не получилось, вернуть приветственную страницу

Нет - вернуть файл указанный в конце пути, если его нет, то вернуть приветственную страницу

Если вы сейчас сделаете запрос по пути `/index.html`, то у вас всё заработает. Чтобы в конце не приходилось писать `index.html` добавьте директиву `index`

Comment: Нет, без равно охватятся абсолютно все страницы сайта, а мне нужно охватить только главную страницу

Comment: @andreymal а файл default не сохранён в папке sites-enabled?

Comment: Нет, предусмотрительно удалён

Comment: @andreymal а если всё-таки равно убрать то начинает работать (на всех страницах)? Нужно для понимания проблемы

Comment: Да, работает. А ещё если я напишу что-то вроде `location = / { return 451; }` то возвращается ошибка 451 как и должно быть (то есть знак равно по идее работает), но вот директивы `root` и `expires`, как написано в тексте вопроса, всё равно напрочь игнорируются

Comment: @andreymal а какие файлы находятся в директории указанной в директиве `root`?

Comment: В тексте вопроса всё это указано

Comment: @andreymal отредактировал свой ответ, кажется проблема в этом

Comment: Я пробовал указывать директиву `index index.html;`, это тоже не помогает (к тому же по умолчанию она всё равно есть, смотрите документацию https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html)

Comment: В этой же документации обнаружился настоящий ответ на вопрос, хех

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что вам сильно усложняет жизнь `location = /` .

Я бы составил конфиг так:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.ru;

  location / {
    root /var/www/test;
  }
  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass ...;
  }
}
```

Comment: Сайт полностью статический, никаких api или proxy_pass нету

Comment: тогда этот классический конфиг будет эффективней (`location /api/` выбросьте). останется добавить try_files и location-ы для страниц ошибок

Comment: Этот конфиг не отключает кэш для главной страницы, поэтому он меня не устраивает

Comment: а для остальных страниц кеш тоже будет включен или выключен?

Comment: А страница всего одна (главная), остальное — совсем уж статические файлы, которые есть смысл кэшировать на какое-то время

Comment: удалить `location /api/`, добавить `expires` и будет норм

Comment: Ну вот именно это я и попытался сделать в тексте вопроса)