# Не работает location в nginx

Tags: nginx

Я только недавно попробовал конфигурировать nginx и столкнулся с проблемой: мне нужно чтобы если я захожу в корень, то отдавалась статика, иначе срабатывал proxy_pass.

Моя конфигурация:

```
location = / {
  root html;
}

location / {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
}
```

Если убрать второе правило, то статика отдаётся правильно, иначе в любом случае срабатыевает proxy_pass, хотя в документации написано, что если встречается `location =` , то поиск прекращается. https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/web-server/#nginx-location-priority

На данный момент единственное рабочее решение:

```
location = / {
  root html;
}

location ~ \/.* {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
}
```

Почему не работает первое решение и как это исправить?

Comment: Вероятно, у вас происходит внутреннее перенаправление на адрес `/index.html`, которому как раз соответствует второй location https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1169927

Comment: Но если вы хотите отдавать существующие статические файлы, а для несуществующих отправлять запрос на proxy_pass, то, вероятно, вам нужно использовать [try_files](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files)

Comment: `location / {
  try_files html @fastapi;
}

location @fastapi {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
}
`
Почему при такой конфигурации заходя на `/` открывается `proxy_pass`?

Comment: Потому что файл `html/html` не существует, видимо

Comment: что в вашем понятии статика ? Только /index.html или картинки, css, js ? Какое их место расположение?